# Sent Ethereum from MetaMask address to same MetaMask address

Tags: transactions, metamask, etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp, meta-transactions

I sent Ethereum from my MetaMask wallet address to the same MetaMask wallet address. I basically sent the funds from myself to myself. The transaction is showing as processed on etherscan however I did not receive the funds I sent. This was an error on my part and hoping I can retrieve the funds somehow.

Comment: Can you provide the tx hash or a link to it on Etherscan ?

Comment: Are you sure that the missing amount isn't due to gas fees ? If it isn't the case, please send tx hash

Comment: Sure - 0x2ac18fdc8e014741e50578055fbbebd1c66b0fb3a252474280f8be42b600ffbc

Comment: 0x2ac18fdc8e014741e50578055fbbebd1c66b0fb3a252474280f8be42b600ffbc

Comment: Strange, you should have it. Are you sure you didn't swap it in your 0.4 ETH swap ?

Comment: Pretty confident that it wasnt included in that as if you see the strong block transaction prior I got roughly .53 and then traded .4 and had roughly .13 remaining. I traded the .4 out of the strong block transaction and the remaining .1 is still outstanding